# Use the same javascript file in both areas

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have JS component which I want to use in both areas: **frontend** and **adminhtml**.

Don't want to duplicate the same file for my module in two locations: `view/frontend/web/js/custom.js` and `view/adminhtml/web/js/custom.js`

Is it possible to place JS in some "global" location, or is there a way to load frontend resource in adminhtml area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the same javascript file in both areas, you would put it in `view/base/web/js/custom.js`